# Postgres - how to split and join?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Is there a way to split a column into tokens, and join them (like you can in other programming languages such as Python, Java, Ruby)

I have a column with urls such as "http://www.Yahoo.com", and I want to extract "Yahoo.com" from it (the main domain, NOT the subdomain). The urls can be of the forms:

- http://www.domain.com
- http://domain.com
- http://domain.com/page/page1
- http://www.domain.com/
- http://www.domain.com/page/page2

I was planning on using a regex to extract everything after http:// and before the next slash. Then splitting the url by the period (.), then joining the last 2 tokens.

With the regex, I can extract www.yahoo.com from http://www.yahoo.com. With the splits/joins, I can get yahoo.com from www.yahoo.com. Problem is I don't know how to do split/joins with Postgres.

Anyone know of a way? Or better alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite the approach you asked for, but should get what you want:

```
vinod=# select * from table;
            url                
----------------------------------
 http://www.domain.com
 http://domain.com
 http://domain.com/page/page1
 http://www.domain.com/page/page2
 http://www.domain.com/
(5 rows)

vinod=# select substring(substring(url from 'http[s]*://([^/]+)') from '\w+\.\w+$') from table;
 substring  
------------
 domain.com
 domain.com
 domain.com
 domain.com
 domain.com
(5 rows)
```

The inner `substring` command pulls out the full domain, and the outer `substring` command pulls out the last two fragments. The Postgresql split and join commands are not as powerful as in your average scripting language, so I tend to do this kind of stuff after I pull things out of the DB, if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting things into tokens can be accomplished in quite a few ways:

- `regexp_split_to_table` / `regexp_split_to_array`
- `string_to_array` (for simple fixed delimter splits)
- Manual `substring` extraction or `substring(... from 'pattern')`
- Full text search's `to_tsvector` and `to_tsquery`
- Procedural language libraries, like Perl or Python URL libraries, Python + NLTK for natural language processing, etc

In this case you could do your URL splitting with a regular expression using `regexp_split_....` and that's probably OK for many uses - but probably not this one. Consider:

- My domain, `ringerc.id.au` (that *is* the "main" domain)
- `www.ecu.edu.au` ("main" domain is `ecu.edu.au`)
- `www.transperth.wa.gov.au` ("main" domain is `transperth.wa.gov.au`)
- `tartarus.uwa.edu.au` ("main" domain is `uwa.edu.au`)

Good luck dealing with all the national registry and sub-registry variations using a regular expression. Use a proper URL parser to extract the domain, then a proper domain-aware library to work out what the "main" domain is for your purposes. I'd recommend using plperl and [the `URL::Split`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.58/URI/Split.pm) or [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.58/URI.pm) modules to start with. Or the URL parser of whatever supported procedural language (Python, TCL, whatever) you want. Then find a suitable library for that language that can identify domains and subdomains meaningfully according to the criteria you want and use that, rather than just relying on a regular expression.

When joining you similarly have many options:

- `array_to_string`
- `string_agg`
- The `||` concatenation operator
- procedural language string operations and libraries

For URL work, again I'd suggest doing this with a PL that has a proper native URL library.

Answer (score 0):

You can match them with `\w+.[^.]+$`

```
http://www.domain.com -> domain.com
http://domain.com -> domain.com
http://domain.com/page/page1 -> domain.com/page/page1
http://www.domain.com/ -> domain.com/
http://www.domain.com/page/page2 -> domain.com/page/page2
```

Comment: Then what about something like `select substring(subtstring(url from '(\w+[.])?\w+[.]\w+') from '\w+[.]\w+$') from table`